# Omega Theme, change content zone when sidebar had no content

Tags: theming

I'm using Omega as Base theme. In the content zone I have 2 regions:

- 'Content region' set as 9 columns
- 'Right column region' set as 3 columns

Is it possible to have a "flexible region"? I want to change the column count when the right column region is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the column count for a region if another region is empty.

1. Go to the layout configuration of the Omega 3 Subtheme
2. Go to the zone that's the parent of the specific region
3. Set "Primary Region" to the region you want to give a flexible column count